# Connecting from one AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I have 2 Elastic Beanstalk environments, "api-server" & "website". Both have a capacity of 1-4 EC2 instances and a load balancer. The load balancer and the instances have both public IP addresses. I want to connect from the "website"  to the "api-server" but i can't get it to work without making the "api-server" public. The "api-server" should not be public.

I am connected with a VPN that is allowed HTTP connections to both EB environments and i can confirm that both apps respond.

Both EB environments have 2 security groups, one for the load balancer called "Load Balancer Security Group" and one for the instances called "VPC Security Group". All load balancer and VPC security groups have an outbound rule allowing all traffic on all protocols.

Since i want to connect from the "website" to any of the instances of "api-server" i want to connect to the load balancer and not to any of the instances directly. So i should add an inbound rule to the load balancer group of the "api-server" that allows traffic from the "website"'s instances.

[image: /Screen Shot 2022-02-06 at 22.32.06.png]

The instances all have the "VPC Security Group" but adding the rule did not give the "website" instances access to the "api-server". I also tried adding the load balancer security group without success. And i also tried the type "All traffic".

I also tried to connect to the "api-server" over different URLs like the load balancer but also no connection possible.

When i add a rule that allows traffic to everywhere, eg. source type "Anywhere-IPv4", i can access the "api-server" from the website. But as i said i don't want the "api-server" public it should be accessible only by the "website".

What also works is adding a rule with the IP address of the current "website" instance, but since they change with deployment of a new version and they are sometimes more or less instances (autoscaled from 1 to 4) its not an option.

So how does it work?

I searched everywhere in the docs but i can't find anything i didn't already tried. What am i missing? This surely shouldn't be so hard?

I appreciate every help!

Edit: Everything is in the same VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how does it work?

Referencing security groups (SGs) works **only withing VPC or peered VPCs**. Since you are accessing your second EB over the internet, not within same VPC, you can't reference SGs.

You have to whitelist public IP addresses of your instances. The best way is to put them in **private subnet** and use NAT gateway. The NAT gives you a single **public static IP** which you can use in your ingress rule of the second EB environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I seem to forgot to mention that everything is in the same VPC. So you’re saying it should work?

Comment: @DanielClausmeyer Then your setup is not clear. Please provide exact description, maybe diagram, what is in public subnets, what is in private subnets, what SGs are you using, which ALB is internet-based, and which one is internal.

Comment: I think i described all of that in the question. I have 2 EB environments, both have load balancers that are public. Both have one security group for the load balancer and one for the EC2 instances. Everything is in the same VPC. I have 3 subnets, on for each of the 3 AZs the instances can be in. I don't know what you mean by "public" or "private" subnet? The option "Auto-assign public IPv4 address" is true for these subnets.

Comment: @DanielClausmeyer You can't access your API endpoint from internet and use SGs referencing. SGs don't work over internet, only within VPC. You can only use private IPs. For that your second ALB must be internal.

Comment: What do you mean with "SGs don't work over internet, only within VPC". As i said everything is in the same VPC. With "second ALB" do you mean the "api-server", the one i want to connect to from the "website"?

Comment: @DanielClausmeyer SGs work only using private IPs, not internet traffic. If the api-server requires a public access (e.g. your front-end will use api through javascript calls), you can't use any SGs referencing to restrict access.

Comment: I understood now, thank you very much! The problem was indeed that the load balancer of the "api-server" was public. I did that because i wanted to access the "api-server" over a VPN for testing, that doesn't work anymore. It does not have to be connected to the internet for production. I changed the load balancer to internal and now i can access it from the "website".